# Can't connect to remote server for lag parsing

Tags: vnc

I've installed SquadJS script via Node.js and Yarn. When trying to deploy, and connect to my remote gaming server for log parsing over FTP, it authenticates, but no connection...I have no firewalls on my VPS, and had some help with one of the Script Devs. Everything is correct, because he can connect on his end, with no issues, but I keep getting the same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Powered by SquadJS, Copyright © 2024
GitHub: https://github.com/Team-Silver-Sphere/SquadJS
Latest Version: 4.0.1, Installed Version: 4.0.1
Your SquadJS version is up to date.
Looking for ways to help protect your server from harmful players?
Checkout the Squad Community Ban List: https://communitybanlist.com/
[SquadServerFactory][1] Reading config file...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Parsing config string...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file chat-commands.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file auto-kick-unassigned.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file db-log.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-admin-broadcast.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-squad-created.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-round-winner.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file team-randomizer.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-killfeed.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-fob-hab-explosion-damage.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-server-status.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-rcon.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-chat.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-roundended.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file socket-io-api.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file auto-tk-warn.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-admin-cam-logs.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file intervalled-broadcasts.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file seeding-mode.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-placeholder.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-subsystem-restarter.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file fog-of-war.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-admin-request.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-teamkill.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file cbl-info.js...
[Plugins][1] Loading plugin file discord-debug.js...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Creating SquadServer...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Preparing connectors...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Starting discord connector discord...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Starting sequelize connector sqlite...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising plugins...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising AutoKickUnassigned...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising AutoTKWarn...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising ChatCommands...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordAdminBroadcast...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordAdminCamLogs...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordAdminRequest...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordChat...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordFOBHABExplosionDamage...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordKillFeed...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordPlaceholder...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordRcon...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordRoundWinner...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordRoundEnded...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordServerStatus...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordSquadCreated...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordSubsystemRestarter...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising DiscordTeamkill...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising SeedingMode...
[SquadServerFactory][1] Initialising TeamRandomizer...
[SquadServer][1] Beginning to watch xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx...
[Layers][1] Pulling layers...
[Layers][1] Pulled 444 layers.
[SquadServer][1] Fetching Admin Lists...
[SquadServer][1] 29 admins loaded...
[RCON][1] Connecting to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
[RCON][1] Connected to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx
[RCON][1] Authentication succeeded.
[SquadServer][1] Updating squad list...
[SquadServer][1] Updated squad list.
[SquadServer][1] Updating player list...
[SquadServer][1] Updated player list.
[SquadServer][1] Updating layer information...
[SquadServer][1] Updated layer information.
[SquadServer][1] Updating server information...
[SquadServer][1] Updated server information.
[LogParser][1] Attempting to watch log file...
FTP Connection ...
(node:8164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Timeout (control socket)
at Socket. (/home/user/Documents/SquadJS-4.0.1/node_modules/basic-ftp/dist/FtpContext.js:316:58)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:631:28)
at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:598:8)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```